# Asking for pin entry on Samsung Watch 6

Tags: samsung-watch-6

I have a Samsung Watch 6 connected to Samsung Note 20.  For some days now, if I swipe the watch face, it shows a numeric keypad on the watch and asks for a pin.  Bezel movement is ignored.

It is obviously some setting that I have played with.  But searching for "lock", "unlock" and "pin" in the `Wear App -> Watch Settings` does not reveal anything useful.

From memory, the only recent changes I have made is to enable `Google Pay` and loaded a visa card.  But I can not find any settings for wearables on `Google Pay`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be Samsung Wallet.  I had tried to get Samsung Wallet working on my new phone and kept getting errors `This card is not supported`.  I didn't really want to use Google Pay, but I had to set it up instead.

`Samsung Wallet` was still enabled for NFC payment.  Which is why it was securing the watch.  I just had to disable payments.